# npm i -g letsencrypt-cli openshift bronze fedora

Tags: python, node.js, openshift, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to emulate [implementation of letsencrypt on Openshift server](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/how-to-use-openshift-paas-with-lets-encrypt-solved/9832) initialized/configured for Node.js.

After failing to install pip with yum, I looked for a similar client to the one referred in the article and identified [the letsencrypt-cli package on npm](https://github.com/Daplie/letsencrypt-cli).

Unfortunately, I can't install the client due to or change the permissions:

```
\> npm install -g letsencrypt-cli@2.x
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /var/lib/openshift/../.npm/letsencrypt-cli/2.1.2/package.tgz
npm ERR! Linux 2.6.32-573.12.1.el6.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "node" "/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "letsencrypt-cli@2.x"
npm ERR! node v0.10.35
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.13
npm ERR! path /opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/lib/node_modules/letsencrypt-cli
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/lib/node_modules/letsencrypt-cli'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/lib/node_modules/letsencrypt-cli']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/lib/node_modules/letsencrypt-cli',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/lib/node_modules/letsencrypt-cli',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ '/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/lib/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23',
npm ERR!      '/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/lib/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:46:53',
npm ERR!      'Object.oncomplete (fs.js:108:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! Linux 2.6.32-573.12.1.el6.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "node" "/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "letsencrypt-cli@2.x"
npm ERR! node v0.10.35
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.13
npm ERR! path npm-debug.log...
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, open 'npm-debug.log...'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, open 'npm-debug.log...']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: 'npm-debug.log...' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/lib/openshift/../npm-debug.log
```

Would anyone happen to know if a more appropriate package or workaround to this issue exists ?

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of ways you might be able to fix the permission problems with npm:

You can change the permissions to match your user:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/node*                # ~/node_modules
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.node*               # .node-gyp
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm*                # .npm .npmrc
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/*/*node*    # node node_modules
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/*/*npm*     # npm
```

You can set the NODE_PATH environment variable for the user and application that you're running:

```
export NODE_PATH=${HOME}/node_modules
```

You can also change your npm settings:

https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions